# cordova installation error -Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not re

Tags: node.js, powershell, cordova, npm, node-modules

I tried to install cordova with " npm install -g cordova"
When I run the command "cordova -v" or "cordova -V" or "cordova --version"
I am getting this error.
Please help to resolve the issue

```
C:\Users\Admin>cordova -v
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
 a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:17
+ (Get-CimInstance <<<<  -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-CimInstance:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



    at makeError (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mcordova←[24m\node_modules\←[4mwindows-release←[24m\node_modules\←[4mexeca←[24m\ind
ex.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mcordova←[24m\node_modules\←[4mwindows-release←[24m\node_modules
\←[4mexeca←[24m\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mcordova←[24m\node_modules\←[4mwindows-release←[24m\index.js:39:19)
    at osName (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mcordova←[24m\node_modules\←[4mos-name←[24m\index.js:39:18)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mcordova←[24m\node_modules\←[4minsight←[24m\lib\index.js:37:13)
    at new RelentlessInsight (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mcordova←[24m\src\telemetry.js:31:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mcordova←[24m\src\telemetry.js:39:15)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)←[39m {
  code: ←[33m1←[39m,
  stdout: ←[32m''←[39m,
  stderr: ←[32m"The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if\r\n"←[39m +
    ←[32m' a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.\r\n'←[39m +
    ←[32m'At line:1 char:17\r\n'←[39m +
    ←[32m'+ (Get-CimInstance <<<<  -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption\r\n'←[39m +
    ←[32m'    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-CimInstance:String) [], CommandNotFoundException\r\n'←[39m +
    ←[32m'    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException\r\n'←[39m +
    ←[32m' \r\n'←[39m,
  failed: ←[33mtrue←[39m,
  signal: ←[1mnull←[22m,
  cmd: ←[32m'powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption'←[39m,
  timedOut: ←[33mfalse←[39m
}

C:\Users\Admin>
```

Comment: So the error is telling you that `Get-Ciminstance` isn't recognised as a command, what powershell version and operatingsystem are you using? `Get-Ciminstance` requires at least powershell v3

Comment: v2 in window 7 professional 32-bit

Comment: from what i can tell, the `CIM-*` cmdlets DO NOT exist in ps2. i suspect the software you are trying to use is NOT compatible with the very old version of windows you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-CimInstance` was introduced in Powershell v3. It was not available previously.

The rough equivalent in Powershell v2 is `Get-WmiObject`, but be advised that that command was superseded and deprecated by the `Get-Cim*` commands. As of Powershell v6, `Get-WmiObject` no longer exists.

Both Powershell v2 and Windows 7 are at end of life (as of January 2020), and should be considered insecure and inappropriate for contemporary usage. That said, Windows 7 does support Powershell v5 through [Windows Management Framework 5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616), although Microsoft is no longer under any obligation to host that file for Windows 7 so it may not remain available.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my powershell to v3. Now it's working fine